# C++ class instantiation theory

Tags: c++, oop

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    A() {
        cout << "Default Ctor" << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    A(); // <------- Problem

    return 0;
}
```

It shows **Default Ctor** on console. My questions

- Is is valid?
- If so, how did it instantiate since I didn't use **new** or any object?

Comment: What do you think `A();` does if it doesn't instantiate something?

Comment: @Mat Yeah, without **new**, it is my doubt

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You **are** creating a new object with `A()`.

**Is is valid?**

Yes it is.

**If so, how did it instantiate since I didn't use new or any object?**

`new` simply creates the object in dynamic memory. You're creating the object in automatic memory. Also, just because you didn't give the object a name, doesn't mean it isn't created.

**Think of this:**

```
int foo() { return 1; }

int main()
{
   foo();
}
```

*Leaving optimizations aside* Did `foo()` actually return `1`? Yes it did. Just that you're not using it.

**EDIT:**

Let's break it down a bit:

```
A();  //creates a temporary unnamed object in automatic storage

A a;   //creates an object a of type A in automatic storage

A a(); //creates no object, but declare a function a returning A and taking no parameters

A a(A());   //these two are equivalent
A a = A();  //creates a temporary unnamed object and creates an object a in automatic storage
            //using the compiler-generated copy constructor

A a;
a = A();    //creates an object a in automatic storage
            //creates an unnamed temporary object and uses the compiler-generated assignment operator
            //to assign it to a

A a = &A(); //invalid, &A() is the address of a temporary a, which is illegal
```

Comment: Then why is it not valid, ** A *object = &A() **

Comment: @Dewsworld the valid syntax would be `A object = A()`.

Comment: "Did foo() actually return 1?" Woah, no need to get philosophical.

Comment: @BoPersson I actually meant `A a`, not `A* a`, since that is what the op asked in the comment.

Answer (score 3):

**Is is valid?**
Yes, It is valid

**What exactly happens?**

```
A();
```

Creates a temporary nameless object of the type `A` by calling its default no argument constructor but the object is destructed by the time the next statement is executed since.

**If so, how did it instantiate since I didn't use new or any object?**
You can create objects on the local/automatic storage or on dynamic storage depending on your usage.

When you use `new` objects are created on dynamic storage(heap), when you create a object as you have it is created on the local/automatic storage(stack).

So using `new` only determines *where* the object will be created not *whether* it will be created.

**What are Temporary Nameless objects?**
You do not always need to name an object to instantiate them.
For Ex:
While calling function, when you pass objects by value *temporary nameless objects* are created and automatically destroyed all the time.These are objects which do not have any name and hence cannot be explicitly referred through program but they do serve the purpose for which they were created.

In simple words,
You are creating a nameless temporary object on the local/automatic storage which does not exist once the statement completes execution.

Comment: @Dewsworld: Accept tick should be reserved for the answer that helped you understand & solve your problem in the best possible way.As long as you did that, no worries :)